# I am taking Calc Ontario gr 12, but have many gaps due to gr 10 and gr 11 functions. Any advice?

Tags: calculus

I am barely managing to pass my classes and it's become increasingly overwhelming dealing with the workload while trying to catch up. There are a lot of topics and I do not know how to start.

I have tried going in YouTube and take notes on topics but as I said it is overly complicated, I need to find a way to understand what to work on and organize the topics to focus and close the gaps. I am planning to use the march break as time to catch up.

Any advice as to how I can deal with this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: My advice is to talk to your teacher, or another teacher at your school. They are in a much better position to give you advice than random strangers on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Khan Academy website has an organized list of precalculus topics: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus. I'm not familiar with Calc Ontario, but you'll probably only need:

- Composite and inverse functions
- Trigonometry
- Rational functions
- Limits and continuity

You can find other important topics like exponentials and logarithms and transformations of functions here: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2